# Using ajax to call a php function on button press then refresh

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, mysqli

I'm trying to make a search page for a mysql database.  I'm trying to get a Next and Previous button to cycle though the search results one result at a time.  I understand that ajax is the best way to do this.
I know very little about ajax.  I'm just now getting a hang of PHP.
I've searched on here but can't find exactly what I want to do.  I have also read though W3's ajax section and it has not helped with this issue.

I have it so that a user searches for items (creates a mysql query) and the search results only outputs one result at a time.  How can I get it so the next result will be displayed on the press of the Next button. Likewise for the Prev button.

I've tried getting if and while statements to work but it seems to keep coming back to a client to server problem.

I was thinking of using a PHP variable to represent each search result and have the button increase/decrease the variable number and tell the page to re-display the information with the new variable.

Any help would be great. I've been stuck on this for more than a week.
Code examples would be even more helpful.

Comment: keep the number of your current  search result in JavaScript code, update it in Prev/Next button handlers, and when searching, send number to your PHP search function

Comment: Is this a Java question (as you've tagged it) or a JavaScript question?

Comment: I am guessing that you're not using Javascript to populate the HTML on your page as you would have had to use an AJAX request to do this. So ultimately, you have a search form, it posts data to the server and the server responds by amending the data that the users sees, the search result. Correct? Try to google the term `php pagination` as this is  what you are trying to do. You will need to use the `LIMIT` clause in order to obtain the correct page of results as per user input, you don't need AJAX, keep it simple and in PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it by doing:

one search request -ajax- to the server and the server responses with an array in JSON format of the results that you are going to navigate throw them by a next and previous buttons, by doing one search request you are going to avoid many requests to server for every next and previous click, and also avoid the server from keeping track of the current result.

---

**The client side - Javascript and JQuery**

```
<script>
var results; // the results array that will have all your search results
var currentresult = 0; // the index of the current result
//the search ajax function
function buttonSearchPressed(){
    $.ajax({type:"POST",url:"test.php",
        data:{keyword:$('input#searchkeyword')[0].value}
        success:function(data){
                try{results = JSON.parse(data)}catch(e){alert('error');}    
        }
    });
}
function previous(){
    if(currentresult>0){
        currentresult--;
        $('span#result')[0].innerHTML =results[currentresult];
    }
}
function next(){
    if(currentresult<results.length-1){
         currentresult++;
         $('span#result')[0].innerHTML =results[currentresult];
     }
}
</script>
```

**The client side - HTML**

[image]

```
<input id="searchkeyword">
<button onclick="buttonSearchPressed()">search</button><br>
<button onclick="previous()">previous</button>
<span id='result'></span>
<button onclick="next()">next</button>
```

**The server side - PHP test.php**

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
   //search ajax handler goes here
   $keyword= $_POST['keyword'];//the search keyword
   //apply the search you want here, (for example database query)
   $searchResult = ["result1","result2","result3","result4","result5"];
   $searchResult = json_encode($searchResult );
   die($searchResult );
}
```